# Is it possible to have an AX Label with Paramters in a SSRS Expression

Tags: ssrs-2012, dynamics-ax-2012

I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish the following.

There is a label in AX, lets call it **@SYS123** which contains the following value: `The sum of {1} and {2} is {3}.`

I would like to use this label in a SSRS expression and was thinking in this direction: `=System.String.Format(Labels!@SYS123, "4", "5", "9")`

But this just gives me #Error.

Is there a way to do this or do I need to concatenate the strings and values to get the desired output?

The reason I would like to make use of the Label is multilanguage support.

Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create label with value: `The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}.`

[Composite format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) string is 0-based.